# Hangfire Dashboard: why missing localization?

Tags: localization, owin, dashboard, hangfire, self-hosting

I'm trying to localize Hangfire Dashboard (inside a self-hosted console OWIN application, .NET Framework 4.6.1). What I don't understand is why it displays right CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture settings, but still default labels? And why are some other labels localized?
[image: Dasboard screenshot]
The picture is from Windows host, but I also tried my app on linux (mono 5.4.2) - it's the same. AFAIK the Hangfire includes "ru" translaion, and uses current cultures to localize the Dashboard. So what's wrong with it?